# BATCH SCRIPT TO PRINT NUMBERS IN WORD FILE

Tags: batch-file, ms-word

Is there a way to print numbers from 1 to 100
i.e, first page print 1.... second page print 2 at the center in a word file
so basically there will be 100 pages with respective numbers on the center of the sheet

Any possible methods

Comment: what you trying to do? what is the need for this? you can type "=rand(200,99)" without quotes and enter in a word document. You will get random text.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place to ask these kind of queries.

Comment: Please add more information to this. I've had a go at trying to figure out what you mean and i'm guessing you want a batch file to display all contents of a document. If so, see my answer and try it.

Comment: Hi All.. Thanks for the reply.
The task given is to print 100 pages of a word file (.docx) with numbers aligned in the center of the word file .
to be more clear the client wanted page1 in word file printed with the number 1 .page2 with 2 centrally aligned.  I guessed may be batch script would help.

Comment: Mr Kumar as you know in a corporate everybody comes running to IT for all requirements like such. I just had a fair idea may be batch script will help to print numbers from 1 to 100 in docx file. I did try to find some scripts ,but its wasnt working for.doc , not beign a programming guy i thought may be the group could help.Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Batch can't interact with Word. You need to use VBA instead.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a word file on your desktop called "Numbers.txt" with numbers 1 to 10, you would do:

```
@echo off
type "C:/Users/%username%/Desktop/Numbers.txt"
pause >nul
```

this would print out all the contents of that .txt file.

Comment: Extremely sorry if i wasnt clear about my requiremnt.

Comment: I need to print numbers from 1 to 100 in .docx file .

Comment: user needs to print 100 pages of a word file .Each page contains the page number printed at the center .For eg. page 1 of the word file will have 1 printed at the center of the page